# Setting the number of `workers` for particular tests in playwright?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I've an e2e test that uses an authenticated user, and uses a button to start a process:

```
load page
-> click start button
   -> load new page
   -> check process ends
   -> click close (process page)
-> click stop button
```

(and if the process is already running, the page offers `reconnect` & `stop` buttons instead)

This is fine, and I have a test that happily hits the `stop` button if the process is marked as running, and continues from there

The flaw with this technique is when testing across three browsers [aka `projects`] - when a 2nd worker starts up, to test the page in a different browser, it spots the process is running [from worker 1]... and shuts the process down - which breaks worker 1.

Running this particular test with `--repeat-each=100 --workers=1`, I get three failures across two browsers (which may be to do with the process-page loading - not sure yet)... so the use of parallel workers is essentially killing that specific test.

Obviously I don't want to run *everything* with just one worker... just those tests where an authenticated user does stuff in the UI.

Is there a way to set specific tests to run on a single worker?

(I can cope if it's at `test`, `test.describe`, or file level... that's just organisation & typing)

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be the same user? You could have them each authenticate with different users (or [a user per worker](https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#moderate-one-account-per-parallel-worker)).

If it does, I don’t believe there’s a way to specify workers at that level from what I can find, but you could use [serial mode](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#serial-mode) so that only one test within that file/describe runs at a time.

Comment: Actually, that probably wouldn’t help if you’re running multiple projects  Perhaps those tests should be their own project? Then turn [fullyParallel off for that project](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testproject#test-project-fully-parallel) so tests within a file don’t run in parallel, and then in the file do a describe per browser (maybe with a loop), and specify the [browserName to test.use](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions#test-options-browser-name). If that actually ends up being the solution you need, I’ll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: It does, really..... I can get _a_ test user into the company authentication system - but trying to get multiple is going to raise questions.  and I don't really want to "mock" that part, because that's going to create more mocked users in the system [though I could, if it was my only option]

Comment: No worries, makes sense. Does the approach I mentioned in my comment work for you then? Or the (probably less recommended) one I gave in the second part of my answer? Both of those would cause one test from that set of tests to run at a time, which I believe is what you needed?

Comment: I'll need to investigate the "make another project" thing - and see how that sits with the current "each browser is a project" config that came out-the-box..... however I _think_ it makes sense.... and I've just discovered the "make a browser in a test" think :)

Comment: I couldn't figure an extra project... in the end I just dropped the whole test suite down to a single worker...

"serial mode" wasn't applicable